# Brown rice in an old rice cooker?

Tags: rice, rice-cooker

A comment on the question about [brown rice making a mess in old rice cookers](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/123110/67) has me wondering:

Is there a proper way to cook brown rice in a mechanical (one button) rice cooker, or do you need a ‘fuzzy logic’ one that can regulate the temperature better?

Currently, I pre-soak the brown rice for about an hour (but don’t rinse again after that soak), and add extra water (well, less rice as I’m using a tiny “3 cup” cooker, which is 1.5 measures on a standard sized rice cooker, so I use about 1/2c brown rice but let it soak, then fill water to line 3)

The water foams up and will come out the vent hole while it’s cooking.

Comment: Are you getting a bad result, overcooked or undercooked?

Comment: @GdD Good result, just messy because of the foaming

Comment: That's how it works.  If you make brown rice in a pot, it also foams.